# During interval timer shooting, NIKON D5600 overexposes photos randomly

Tags: timelapse, nikon-d5600

I am having an issue with my camera. At random, it will overexpose photos during interval timer shooting. It's generally fine at the beginning, but as time goes on, there are more and more overexposed shots. The time on those shots is the same as on the ones that are properly exposed.

I am thinking that either the aperture is not being set properly on the lens, or the shutter is broken.

**How can I diagnose this so that I can know if I need to get anything fixed?** (*It never happened when I was taking pictures normally*).

Here's my last timelapse, you can see the overexposed shots:

[image]

Comment: Have you consider to take photos in Manual mode?

Comment: What shutter speed? What lighting source? What exposure mode?

Comment: "*The time on those shots is the same as on the ones that are properly exposed.*"  **Is the amount of light the same??, One would assume not.** (*It probably has nothing to do with randomness*)

Comment: Manual or auto mode? what lens? Is the exif/exposure data the same in all images? And more important: was the light source a continuous one? or maybe a neon light with a frequency of oscillation?

Comment: If the light source "blinks", e.g. LED or fluorescent lamps, you might capture light from two blinks on occasion, and from one others.